# How to increase the value of text field on page load in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to increase the value of text field on page load in JavaScript.
For example

```
<input type="text" name="itemquantity[]" value="1"/>
```

after pageload it shoud be  like

```
<input type="text" name="itemquantity[]" value="2"/>
```

Comment: you can do it in server-side code.which programming language are you using?

Comment: No need to use server-side code for just refreshing the values. JavaScript can handle it. Make the use of HTML5

Comment: Do you want each page load to increase the value of the input ?

Comment: @dystroy yes i'm wanted to increase the value on page load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
<input id="myid" type="text" name="itemquantity[]" value="1"/>
<script>
   localStorage['myid'] =
      document.getElementById('myid').value =
          parseInt(localStorage['myid'] || '0', 10) + 1;
</script>
```

At each load of the page, the value will be incremented by 1, with initial value being 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="textField1" type="text" name="itemquantity[]" value="1"/>

<script>
window.onload=function()
{
document.getElementById('textField1').value=document.getElementById('textField1').value+1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the use of cookie or localStorage to achieve this. As each time the page is loaded state of web page is lost, so localStorage is at rescue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="result"></div>
<script>
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
 if(localStorage.itemquantity) {
  localStorage.itemquantity = parseInt(localStorage.itemquantity, 10) +1;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Value: " + localStorage.itemquantity;
}
else
{
    localStorage.itemquantity = 1;
}
  }
else
  {
alert('browser does not support local storage');
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As now you have the value you can assign it to the text-field

**UPDATE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")  
{  
 if(localStorage.itemquantity) {  
  localStorage.itemquantity = parseInt(localStorage.itemquantity, 10) +1;  
  document.getElementById("txtFieldID").value = localStorage.itemquantity;  
}  
else  
{  
    localStorage.itemquantity = 1;  
}  
  }  
else  
  {  
alert('browser does not support local storage');  
  }  
</script>
```

**NOTE** Keep `txtFieldID` as your textbox ID, at the first load the value will be set to 1 and with every load it will increment by 1
Hope this helps

Comment: Is that the answer for the question?

Comment: The localStorage.itemquantity now has the updated value (every time the page is refreshed), so this value can be used to update the TEXTFIELD. Isn't this okay?

Comment: This looks like a step in the right direction. Can't you put the input in your sample and update it ?