# how to increment the value in the span on page load in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wanted to increment the value between the  tag in javascript 
for example

```
<span class="quantity">1</span>
```

after page load it will be like this

```
<span class="shopp-quantity">2</span>
```

Comment: Do you really want to change the class name after reload ?

Comment: @dystroy That suggested duplicate is about changing the `value` attribute, not the text in the span.

Comment: @Barmar I know (as I answered it too). That's why I asked if it was a duplicate. Compare my answers to both questions : you'll see I don't think that's a very different problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the same than [yesterday's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14728228/how-to-increase-the-value-of-text-field-on-page-load-in-javascript) :

```
<span class="quantity"></span>
<script>
   localStorage['myid'] =
      document.getElementsByClassName('quantity')[0].innerHTML =
          parseInt(localStorage['myid'] || '0') + 1;
</script>
```